# Copying data to next sheet in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have data from column a, b & c in worksheet Sheet1. I need to copy those data to sheet3 a, b & C column. Then i need to go  to sheet2 and column a, b & c contains similar data like sheet1, i need to copy that data and paste in sheet3 below where i already pasted data from sheet1.
Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: You may be better off taking a screendump of your excel sheets with visual descriptions of what you need. Currently it is very difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/copy-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another/

first hit on google when you search for "excel copy data from one sheet to another VB" 
and i only typed excel copy and VB the rest was autocompleted

edit: i would vote down, but i can't :P